# Sending JSON data to server from Android ... code works as java project in eclipse but not when run on phone

Tags: java, android, json, http, push-notification

This works as a normal Java project but when called from the app it gives the error below. I am trying to send the registration id for push notifications to my server using JSON format.

```
public class SendID extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... regID){
    URL url;
    String response = "";
    try {
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
        json.put("lemons", "limes");
        String stuff = json.toString();

        url = new URL("http://138.67.236.100:8080/notifications/rest/push");

        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setReadTimeout(80000);
        conn.setConnectTimeout(60000);
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
       // conn.setDoInput(true);
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        conn.setFixedLengthStreamingMode(stuff.getBytes().length);

        conn.connect();
        OutputStream os = new BufferedOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());



        os.write(stuff.getBytes());
        os.close();

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
        System.out.println("REST SERVICE SUCCESS");
        in.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("REST SERVICE FAILED");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return "";
}
}
```

Here is the error message I get, there is a timeout exception even though the timeout is set to a minute.

```
06-05 12:18:27.951  16633-16870/com.example.zheng.gcm_client01 I/System.out﹕ REST SERVICE FAILED
06-05 12:18:27.951  16633-16870/com.example.zheng.gcm_client01 W/System.err﹕ java.net.SocketTimeoutException: failed to connect to /IPHERE (port 8080) after 60000ms
06-05 12:18:27.951  16633-16870/com.example.zheng.gcm_client01 W/System.err﹕ at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:169)
06-05 12:18:27.951  16633-16870/com.example.zheng.gcm_client01 W/System.err﹕ at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:122)
06-05 12:18:27.951  16633-16870/com.example.zheng.gcm_client01 W/System.err﹕ at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:183)
06-05 12:18:27.951  16633-16870/com.example.zheng.gcm_client01 W/System.err﹕ at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:456)
06-05 12:18:27.951  16633-16870/com.example.zheng.gcm_client01 W/System.err﹕ at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:882)
06-05 12:18:27.951  16633-16870/com.example.zheng.gcm_client01 W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okhttp.internal.Platform.connectSocket(Platform.java:139)
06-05 12:18:27.951  16633-16870/com.example.zheng.gcm_client01 W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connect(Connection.java:1194)
06-05 12:18:27.951  16633-16870/com.example.zheng.gcm_client01 W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:393)
06-05 12:18:27.951  16633-16870/com.example.zheng.gcm_client01 W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:296)
06-05 12:18:27.951  16633-16870/com.example.zheng.gcm_client01 W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:399)
06-05 12:18:27.951  16633-16870/com.example.zheng.gcm_client01 W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:110)
06-05 12:18:27.951  16633-16870/com.example.zheng.gcm_client01 W/System.err﹕ at com.example.zheng.gcm_client01.SendID.doInBackground(SendID.java:45)
06-05 12:18:27.951  16633-16870/com.example.zheng.gcm_client01 W/System.err﹕ at com.example.zheng.gcm_client01.SendID.doInBackground(SendID.java:23)
06-05 12:18:27.951  16633-16870/com.example.zheng.gcm_client01 W/System.err﹕ at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
06-05 12:18:27.951  16633-16870/com.example.zheng.gcm_client01 W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
06-05 12:18:27.951  16633-16870/com.example.zheng.gcm_client01 W/System.err﹕ at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
06-05 12:18:27.951  16633-16870/com.example.zheng.gcm_client01 W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
06-05 12:18:27.951  16633-16870/com.example.zheng.gcm_client01 W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
06-05 12:18:27.951  16633-16870/com.example.zheng.gcm_client01 W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Comment: Are you sure you have internet connectivity and all the necessary permissions in the manifest?

Comment: And that the DNS is correct and returning the right IP?

Comment: Try changing /IPHERE to an actual IP address or Domain.

Comment: The log is not related to the code you pasted. In the code you are using *HttpURLConnection* and the log is about *okhttp*